# Why I can't clone this GitHub repository when I am under a proxy?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I am pretty new in Git and GitHub and I think I have some configuration problem.

Yesterday I have correctly configured the SSH connection between my local GIT and my GitHub account. It works fine.

Today I go to the office where I am under a proxy and using the same laptop I try to clone a remote repository (on my GitHub account) to my local repository.

The proxy is correctly setted on my Git, in fact doing:

```
$ git config --global http.proxy
http://XX.YY.ZZ.AAA:3228
```

That is the same proxy that I use to navigate on Internet that I have setted into the browser settings.

The problem is that when I try to clone my repository on GitHub into my local repository I obtain this error message:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:AndreaNobili/recipes.git
Cloning into 'recipes'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If I connect to Internet using my smartphone connection (that is not under proxy) it works fine.

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: That port 22 is most probably closed on the proxy server. Try to clone via https - (https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git). That should work cause port 443 should be open on a web proxy

Comment: Try setting `http_proxy` environment variable. If you already have `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable set, try the lower case version.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar I have http_proxy setted, I am under Windows so I think that is not case sensitive

Comment: @sestus How can I clone via https instead via SSH?

Comment: @AndreaNobili when you go to your github repo page on the website and click on the green `Clone or Download` button, you should see a `Use HTTPS` option there.

Comment: @AndreaNobili use this: `git clone https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've configured an http proxy, you haven't instructed Git to use http - you've specified that it should use ssh to connect:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:AndreaNobili/recipes.git
```

And indeed, your error message is that ssh timed out:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

This happens because you have a firewall blocking your connection.  Instead, specify the repository as an HTTP URL, and Git will use the corporate proxy you've configured:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the environment variable as `http_proxy` as `curl` and `libcurl` don't seem to recognize upper case variable `HTTP_PROXY`.

[This link](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2001-12/0034.html) elaborates more on that:

> The variable "HTTP_PROXY", using all caps, is no longer permitted/understood
>   (since 7.7.2 actually).
>
> Here's why:
>   When CGI scripts get executed from within web servers, they usually get
>   environment variables set before the script is executed. Headers in the
>   incoming request that activate the script get converted to variables named
>   HTTP_[header].
>
> So, if anyone wrote a CGI script that in turn was using curl, you could
>   actually trick curl to use a http proxy of your choice by passing a 'Proxy:
>   [yada yada]' header.
>
> http_proxy', using lower case, on the other hand is perfectly understood by
>   curl.

Comment: If you see my original post I have correctly setted the http_proxy. What you means that it have to be setted as curl?

Comment: No, you don't have to set anything as `curl`. `curl` is a URL transfer library. But since, you are using Windows, the case for the environment variables should not matter.